# how can i tell if a javascript function works across browsers

Tags: javascript

How can I tell if a given javascript function will work across browsers? For instance, I want to use String.trim() and I see that it works in Firefox, but will it work in all the other major browsers? I imagine there is a good doc online somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: There's no such thing as String.trim() in JavaScript, at least not as part of the standard API

Comment: @Donal its part of the ECMAScript 5 spec. and most browsers have implemented it (besides IE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuirksMode can give you information but mostly about CSS and DOM.

`String.prototype.trim` is a new method, from the [ECMAScript 5th Edition Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

To check the availability of the new ES5 methods on various browsers, give a look to the following table:

- [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

Usually if you are checking which built-in *standard* methods are available and work propertly across browsers, you can run conformance tests:

- [Sputnik](http://sputnik.googlelabs.com/) (tests ES3 conformance)
- [ECMAScript 5 Conformance Suite](http://es5conform.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That's true - there's not much at Quirksmode about the Javascript standard classes.

Comment: @Pointy yep, they focus on W3C standards, DOM Core, Events, CSS, etc... but not too much on the built-in ECMA-262 features.

Answer (score 3):

Try quirksmode, for starters: http://quirksmode.org

Comment: Does quirksmode provide compatibility info for core JavaScript functions, i.e not just DOM object methods?

Comment: No, to be honest it's mostly DOM stuff. See the answer @CMS gave.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Dynamic HTML The Definitive Reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565924949) by Danny Goodman is a huge help for this type of research.

For example, for the function String.replace(), it tells me it is supported by the following browsers and versions (since): IE 4, NN 4, Moz *all*, Saf *all*, Op 7, and has been included in ECMA 3.

Comment: I purchased the first and second editions of this and for years it was rarely off my desk, however isn't it a bit out of date now?  I can't see a new edition on Amazon. +1 anyway for a classic.

Comment: There's a third edition that came out 2-3 years ago. As a reference it's OK. As a guide to writing JavaScript I'd take it with a large pinch of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [W3Schools JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) site, especially the complete references for the various objects. As an example, here's the [complete `String` reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp).